# How can I get all of the <tr> elements in a specific <table>?

Tags: c#, html-agility-pack, tablerow

Currently I have this for each loop:

```
var table = document.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//*[@id=\"NpcTable\"]/tbody");

foreach (var row in table)
{
    HtmlAttribute attr = row.Attributes["role"];
    Console.WriteLine("<tr> Element Successfully Found.");
}
```

This only seems to find one `<tr>` element, but I'm not entirely sure. 
This is the output: `<tr> Element Successfully Found.`, but only once.

Comment: explore the accuracy of your path string `//tr[@role]` by debugging

Comment: @JohnB Alright, so I changed the XPath to be more specific to the table I want to get. The new XPath is `//*[@id=\"NpcTable\"]/tbody`, but this only prints a blank line, even with the more accurate xpath.

Answer (score 0):

```
var table = document.DocumentNode.Descendants("tr").Where(node => node.Attributes.Contains("role")).ToList();
    foreach (var row in table)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(row.InnerText);
    }
```

Comment: While this might answer the authors question, it lacks some explaining words and links to documentation. Raw code snippets are not very helpful without some phrases around it. You may also find [how to write a good answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer) very helpful. Please edit your answer.

Comment: Using this code no longer throws the error that I was getting before, but since there is no inner text for that element, it just prints a blank line.